# How to list installed packages and environment variables in pytest-html report?

Tags: selenium, pytest, pytest-html

I have a framework with selenium + python tests and I need to use `pytest-html` to get and show the info about installed packages and environment variables in the generated report. My only thought was to get `extra.html` and write a scipt which will run `pip list` for packages but this looks like an overhead.

Any advices are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turned out it was pretty easy to do. I had to use common `os` library:

```
import os
    def _pytest_configure_(config):
        config.metadata['os'] = os.name
        config.metadata['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH']
        config.metadata['pwd'] = os.getcwd()
```

and put this into a repor, then run `python3 -m pytest -v --html=report.html`